# c++11: building a std::tuple from a template function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following function:

```
template<class T>
T Check(int index);
```

*How can I write a function, `CheckTuple`, which, given a tuple type, populates a tuple with calls to `Check`?*

For example:

```
CheckTuple< std::tuple<int, float, std::string> >()
```

would return the following tuple:

```
std::make_tuple( Check<int>(1), Check<float>(2), Check<std::string>(3) )
```

The other questions I see involve unpacking a given tuple, not building one up this way.

Comment: Are you familiar with variadic template functions?

Comment: A bit. I've started using them in the past few days.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @TomaszKłak, I'm trying to learn how to do things with variadic template functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing what you're looking for becomes pretty simple using C++14's [`integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). If you don't have that available, [here's a C++11 implementation](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/source/24293c100405bf3982732f53897b4beb962a9086:integer_seq.h) written by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely).

```
template<typename Tuple, int... I>
Tuple CallCheck(std::integer_sequence<int, I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(Check<typename std::tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type>(I)...);
}

template<typename Tuple>
Tuple CheckTuple()
{
    return CallCheck<Tuple>(std::make_integer_sequence<int, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
}

// Use it as 
auto tup = CheckTuple<std::tuple<int, float, std::string>>();
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5230fc856df021da)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working test implementation. (Perhaps someone has an idea of how to improve upon it in terms of conciseness. Can I get rid of TupleInfo somehow?)

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
T Check(int i) {
    std::cout << "getting a " << typeid(T).name() << " at position " << i << std::endl;
    return T();
}

template<typename Signature>
struct TupleInfo;

template<class T, class... Args>
struct TupleInfo< std::tuple<T, Args...> > {
    using Head = T;
    using Tail = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<int N, class Tuple>
struct TupleChecker {

    static Tuple CheckTuple() {
        auto t = std::make_tuple(Check<typename TupleInfo<Tuple>::Head>(N));
        return std::tuple_cat(t, TupleChecker<N+1, typename TupleInfo<Tuple>::Tail >::CheckTuple());
    }

};

template<int N>
struct TupleChecker<N, std::tuple<> > {

    static std::tuple<> CheckTuple() {
        return std::tuple<>();
    }

};

template<class Tuple>
Tuple CheckTuple() {
    return TupleChecker<1, Tuple>::CheckTuple();
}

int main() {

    std::tuple<> t0 = CheckTuple<std::tuple<> >();

    std::tuple<int> t1 = CheckTuple<std::tuple<int> >();

    std::tuple<int, float, std::string> t2 = CheckTuple<std::tuple<int, float, std::string> >();

    return 0;

}
```