# non-void function template recursive over tuples and vectors

Tags: templates, c++11, stdvector, stdtuple

I've made a function that calculates the sine of a number. It returns the input type if it is `std::is_floating_point`. But for `std::is_integral`, it returns a `double`.

```
template<class T , typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
double mysin(const T& t) // note, function signature is unmodified
{
    double a = t;
    return std::sin(a);
}

template<class T , typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
T mysin(const T& t) // note, function signature is unmodified
{
    return std::sin(t);
}
```

Easy enough. Now I'd like this to work for `vector`s (or arrays) and `tuple`s (or clusters). So that:

```
(pseudo code:)
std::vector<std::double> a = mysin(std::vector<std::int>); 
std::tuple<std::double, std::float> b = mysin(std::tuple<std::int, std::float>);
std::vector<std::tuple<std::double, std::float>> c = mysin(std::vector<std::tuple<std::int, std::float>>);
std::tuple<std::vector<std::double>, std::float> d = mysin(std::tuple<std::vector<std::int>, std::float>);
std::tuple<std::tuple<std::double, std::vector<std::double>>, std::float>> e = mysin(std::tuple<std::tuple<std::int, std::vector<std::int>>, std::float>>);
and so on...
```

In most examples about `tuple` templates, the function either has no return value, returns an accumulated value, or has the same return type as the input.

I've experimented a lot with these topics (among others):
[Traversing nested C++11 tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605944/traversing-nested-c11-tuple?rq=1) , [c++11: building a std::tuple from a template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936332/c11-building-a-stdtuple-from-a-template-function) , [How to make a function that zips two tuples in C++11 (STL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322095/how-to-make-a-function-that-zips-two-tuples-in-c11-stl)

The last one has been especially useful. I've got this working for `tuple`s, but not for recursive `tuples` (`tuple`s in `tuple`s).

Eventually (if this is possible at all), I'll have to make a `mycos`, `mytan`, `myasin`, etc. Using gcc 4.9.2.

**EDIT:**So this is what I came up with after Yakk's suggestions, and a little tweaking:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo> // used for typeid
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdlib> // for math functions?
#include <cmath> // for math functions
#include <type_traits> // for std::enable_if

template<class T , typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
double mysin(const T& t) { // note, function signature is unmodified
    double a = t;
    return std::sin(a);
// printing a debug string here will
// print tuple elements reversed!!
}


template<class T , typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr >
T mysin(const T& t) {// note, function signature is unmodified
// printing a debug string here will
// print tuple elements reversed!!
    return std::sin(t);
}

struct sine_t {
    template<class T>
    auto operator()(T&&t)const->
        decltype(mysin(std::declval<T>())) {
            return mysin(std::forward<T>(t));
            }
};

template<class F>
struct vectorize {
    template<class T,
        class R=std::vector< std::result_of_t< vectorize<F>(T const&) > >
    >
        R operator()( std::vector<T> const& v ) const {
            R ret;
            ret.reserve(v.size());
            for( auto const& e : v ) {
                ret.push_back( vectorize<F>{}(e) );
                }
        return ret;
        }

    template<
        class X,
        class R=std::result_of_t< F(X const&) >
    >
        R operator()( X const& x ) const {
            return F{}(x);
            }   

    template<
        class R, 
        class... Ts, 
        size_t... Is
    >
    R tup_help( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ) const {
        return std::make_tuple( vectorize<F>{}(std::get<Is>(t))... );
        }

    template<
        class... Ts,
        class R=std::tuple< std::result_of_t< vectorize<F>(Ts const&) >... >
    >
    R operator()( std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ) const {
        return tup_help<R>( std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, t );
        }

    };

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1 ,2};
    std::tuple<int, double, int, double> b (42, -3.14, 42, -3.14);

    auto c = vectorize<sine_t>()(a);
    auto d = vectorize<sine_t>()(b);

    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int> > e {std::make_tuple(1 ,2)};
    //This does not not work:
    //auto f = vectorize<sine_t>()(e);

    //This works:
    std::tuple<std::vector<int> > g ( a );
    auto f = vectorize<sine_t>()(g);

    return 0;
}
```

This works. Needs c++14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an overload set object.  This is useful because it lets us pass around the entire overload set as a single object:

```
struct sine_t {
  template<class T>
  auto operator()(T&&t)const->
  decltype(mysin(std::declval<T>()))
  { return mysin(std::forward<T>(t)); }
};
```

next, we want to "vectorize" a given function object.

We'll start simple:

```
template<class F>
struct vectorize {
  template<class T, class R=std::vector< std::result_of_t< F(T const&) > >>
  R operator()( std::vector<T> const& v ) const {
    R ret;
    ret.reserve(v.size());
    for( auto const& e : v ) {
      ret.push_back( F{}(e) );
    }
    return ret;
  }
  template<class X, class R=std::result_of_t< F(X const&) >>
  R operator()( X const& x ) const {
    return F{}(x);
  }
};
```

this supports 1 level recursion, and only on `std::vector`.

To allow infinite recursion of nested `std::vector`s, we modify the `operator()` overload for `std::vector`:

```
  template<
    class T,
    class R=std::vector< std::result_of_t< vectorize<F>(T const&) > >
  >
  R operator()( std::vector<T> const& v ) const {
    R ret;
    ret.reserve(v.size());
    for( auto const& e : v ) {
      ret.push_back( vectorize<F>{}(e) );
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

and now we support `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

For tuple support, we add 2 functions.  The first one has this signature:

```
  template<
    class... Ts,
    class R=std::tuple< std::result_of_t< vectorize<F>(Ts const&) >... >
  >
  R operator()( std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ) const
```

which gets us our return value (half the battle).  To actually do the mapping, use the indexes trick:

```
  template<
    class R,
    class... Ts,
    size_t... Is
  >
  R tup_help( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ) const
  {
    return std::make_tuple( vectorize<F>{}(std::get<Is>(t))... );
  }
  template<
    class... Ts,
    class R=std::tuple< std::result_of_t< vectorize<F>(Ts const&) >... >
  >
  R operator()( std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ) const {
    return tup_help<R>( std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, t );
  }
```

similar code for `std::array` and raw C arrays should work (converting the raw C array to a `std::array` naturally).

`std::index_sequence` etc is C++14, but easy to write a version that supports 100s of elements in C++11.  (A version that supports large arrays takes more work).  The `result_of_t` alias (and any similar) are also C++14, but the aliases are easy to write in C++11, or you can just `typename std::result_of<?>::type` verbose explosion.

In the end, you `vectorize<sine_t>{}` and pass in whatever.

If you want a function instead of a function object, simply have it delegate the work to `vectorize<sine_t>`.

Comment: @wiebe yes, `vectorize<F>{}(e)`   I will try to fix typos that break the call later today: debugging SFINAE errors is tricky sometimes.  The idea is that `sine_t` calls a bunch of overloads of a free function is useful.  You can gice it a different name (`my_sin_element`), thrn write `my_sine<T>` as calling `vectorize<sine_t>{}(t)`.

Comment: don't know why I got to see your comment only after I deleted my comment today... Anyway, you've got me to 95%, and the other 5% was a good learning experience. Note the "s" behind std::index_sequences. It's the only mistake, otherwise your code was perfect, I just didn't understand the vectorize<sine_t>{}(t) syntax. Is it better then vectorize<sine_t>()(t) ? Thanks.

Comment: @Wiebe It makes it clear that I am constructing an object, as opposed to calling a function.  That is about it.

Comment: Hmm. Have to read Item 7, Effective Modern C++. It's about () vs. {}. Still at Item 3... By the way, it does not work for tuple vectors (vector <tuple< int, double> > ). Compiler says there's no template. Tuples, vectors and integrals work fine. Vector tuples works as well.

Comment: Ok, fixed the tuple vector problem. class R=std::vector< std::result_of_t< F(T const&) > > should be class R=std::vector< std::result_of_t< vectorize<F>(T const&) > >, or it won't recurse the vector type.

Comment: @Wiebe Yes.  Was that an error I have above that I missed, or was it an error in your version of the code?

Comment: \@Yakk. Don't know. I think I mostly copy-pasted that part. Anyway it's working! I made more changed as my understanding of it grows. I've put the double\integers construction inside the struct as well. This makes it less flexible, but since I want all math functions (sin, cos etc.) to behave like this, it makes sense to reuse the code. I also adjusted the templates to accept more then one parameter. But the vectorization is only done on the first parameter. Thanks again for the help.